# Cannot start instance: nbd device allocation failed

Tags: openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I used AutoPilot to do an install of OpenStack. on a couple compute nodes when I try to provision the VM I get the following error in nova-compute.log

```
2015-05-14 19:38:07.807 7494 WARNING nova.virt.disk.mount.nbd [-] No free nbd devices
2015-05-14 19:38:07.807 7494 INFO nova.virt.disk.mount.api [-] Device allocation failed. Will retry in 2 seconds.
2015-05-14 19:38:22.884 7494 ERROR nova.network.linux_net [-] Unable to execute ['ovs-vsctl', '--timeout=120', '--', '--if-exists', 'del-port', u'qvo6a2b71b0-f4', '--', 'add-port', 'br-int', u'qvo6a2b71b0-f4', '--', 'set', 'Interface', u'qvo6a2b71b0-f4', u'external-ids:iface-id=6a2b71b0-f4dd-4346-8ce3-cf37d3bee46a', 'external-ids:iface-status=active', u'external-ids:attached-mac=fa:16:3e:eb:dd:ae', 'external-ids:vm-uuid=4fc5ca8c-d353-4e3d-b953-998eb6b32370']. Exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: sudo nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf ovs-vsctl --timeout=120 -- --if-exists del-port qvo6a2b71b0-f4 -- add-port br-int qvo6a2b71b0-f4 -- set Interface qvo6a2b71b0-f4 external-ids:iface-id=6a2b71b0-f4dd-4346-8ce3-cf37d3bee46a external-ids:iface-status=active external-ids:attached-mac=fa:16:3e:eb:dd:ae external-ids:vm-uuid=4fc5ca8c-d353-4e3d-b953-998eb6b32370
Exit code: 1
Stdout: u''
Stderr: u'2015-05-14T19:38:22Z|00002|reconnect|WARN|unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: connection attempt failed (Protocol error)\novs-vsctl: unix:/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (Protocol error)\n'
2015-05-14 19:38:22.885 7494 ERROR nova.compute.manager [-] [instance: 4fc5ca8c-d353-4e3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Environment configuration, in auto pilot I configured: KVM, Open vSwitch, Ceph,Ceph.

Here is my landscape juju status:

```
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-2:~$ juju status
environment: "1"
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.1
    dns-name: dumbledor.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-89fd853a-f5c3-11e4-bf21-0015c5607ff0/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      0/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.150
        instance-id: juju-machine-0-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      0/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.151
        instance-id: juju-machine-0-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=4 mem=8192M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.1
    dns-name: malfoy.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-a91bece8-f50c-11e4-b4ed-0015c5607ff0/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      1/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.158
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      1/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.159
        instance-id: juju-machine-1-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=4 mem=8192M
  "2":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.1
    dns-name: voldemort.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-bcc0e8c6-f515-11e4-b4ed-0015c5607ff0/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      2/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.153
        instance-id: juju-machine-2-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      2/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.154
        instance-id: juju-machine-2-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      2/lxc/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.156
        instance-id: juju-machine-2-lxc-2
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=4096M
  "3":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.1
    dns-name: weasley.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-70ff0c70-f550-11e4-bf17-0015c5607ff0/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      3/lxc/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.160
        instance-id: juju-machine-3-lxc-0
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      3/lxc/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.161
        instance-id: juju-machine-3-lxc-1
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
      3/lxc/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        dns-name: 10.10.1.162
        instance-id: juju-machine-3-lxc-2
        series: trusty
        hardware: arch=amd64
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=4 mem=32768M
services:
  ceph:
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-31
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/ceph-36
    exposed: false
    relations:
      client:
      - cinder
      - glance
      - landscape-client
      - nova-compute
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      mon:
      - ceph
      osd:
      - ceph-osd
      radosgw:
      - ceph-radosgw
    units:
      ceph/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "0"
        public-address: dumbledor.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/0:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: dumbledor.maas
      ceph/1:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "2"
        public-address: voldemort.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/7:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: voldemort.maas
      ceph/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "3"
        public-address: weasley.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/9:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: weasley.maas
  ceph-osd:
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-osd-5
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/ceph-osd-10
    exposed: false
    relations:
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      mon:
      - ceph
    units:
      ceph-osd/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "1"
        public-address: malfoy.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/8:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: malfoy.maas
  ceph-radosgw:
    charm: cs:trusty/ceph-radosgw-8
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/ceph-radosgw-12
    exposed: false
    relations:
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      mon:
      - ceph
    units:
      ceph-radosgw/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 3/lxc/2
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        public-address: 10.10.1.162
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/11:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.162
  cinder:
    charm: cs:trusty/cinder-10
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/cinder-23
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      ceph:
      - ceph
      cinder-volume-service:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      cluster:
      - cinder
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      image-service:
      - glance
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      cinder/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 2/lxc/2
        public-address: 10.10.1.156
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/16:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.156
  glance:
    charm: cs:trusty/glance-9
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/glance-20
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      ceph:
      - ceph
      cluster:
      - glance
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      image-service:
      - cinder
      - nova-cloud-controller
      - nova-compute
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      glance/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 3/lxc/0
        open-ports:
        - 9292/tcp
        public-address: 10.10.1.160
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/15:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.160
  keystone:
    charm: cs:trusty/keystone-9
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/keystone-25
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - keystone
      identity-service:
      - ceph-radosgw
      - cinder
      - glance
      - neutron-api
      - nova-cloud-controller
      - openstack-dashboard
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      keystone/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "identity-service-relation-changed" for neutron-api:identity-service'
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 0/lxc/0
        public-address: 10.10.1.150
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/4:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.150
  landscape-client:
    charm: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/landscape-client-12
    exposed: false
    relations:
      ceph-client:
      - ceph
      container:
      - ceph
      - ceph-osd
      - ceph-radosgw
      - cinder
      - glance
      - keystone
      - mysql
      - neutron-api
      - neutron-gateway
      - nova-cloud-controller
      - nova-compute
      - ntpmaster
      - openstack-dashboard
      - rabbitmq-server
    subordinate-to:
    - ceph
    - ceph-osd
    - ceph-radosgw
    - cinder
    - glance
    - keystone
    - mysql
    - neutron-api
    - neutron-gateway
    - nova-cloud-controller
    - nova-compute
    - ntpmaster
    - openstack-dashboard
    - rabbitmq-server
  mysql:
    charm: cs:trusty/percona-cluster-13
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/percona-cluster-21
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      shared-db:
      - cinder
      - glance
      - keystone
      - neutron-api
      - neutron-gateway
      - nova-cloud-controller
      - nova-compute
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "config-changed"'
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 2/lxc/0
        public-address: 10.10.1.153
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/10:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.153
  neutron-api:
    charm: cs:trusty/neutron-api-5
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/neutron-api-14
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      cluster:
      - neutron-api
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      neutron-api:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      neutron-plugin-api:
      - neutron-openvswitch
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      neutron-api/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 1/lxc/0
        open-ports:
        - 9696/tcp
        public-address: 10.10.1.158
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/13:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.158
  neutron-gateway:
    charm: cs:trusty/quantum-gateway-8
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/quantum-gateway-16
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      cluster:
      - neutron-gateway
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      - ntp
      quantum-network-service:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      neutron-gateway/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "0"
        public-address: dumbledor.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/1:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: dumbledor.maas
          ntp/0:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/ntp-6
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: dumbledor.maas
  neutron-openvswitch:
    charm: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-1
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-7
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      neutron-plugin:
      - nova-compute
      neutron-plugin-api:
      - neutron-api
    subordinate-to:
    - nova-compute
  nova-cloud-controller:
    charm: cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-50
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-56
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      cinder-volume-service:
      - cinder
      cloud-compute:
      - nova-compute
      cluster:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      image-service:
      - glance
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      neutron-api:
      - neutron-api
      quantum-network-service:
      - neutron-gateway
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      nova-cloud-controller/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 2/lxc/1
        open-ports:
        - 3333/tcp
        - 8773/tcp
        - 8774/tcp
        - 9696/tcp
        public-address: 10.10.1.154
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/17:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.154
  nova-compute:
    charm: cs:trusty/nova-compute-11
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/nova-compute-24
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      ceph:
      - ceph
      cloud-compute:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      compute-peer:
      - nova-compute
      image-service:
      - glance
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      - ntp
      neutron-plugin:
      - neutron-openvswitch
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      nova-compute/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "cloud-compute-relation-changed" for nova-cloud-controller:cloud-compute'
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "1"
        public-address: malfoy.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/3:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: malfoy.maas
          neutron-openvswitch/0:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-1
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: malfoy.maas
          ntp/1:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/ntp-6
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: malfoy.maas
      nova-compute/1:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "cloud-compute-relation-changed" for nova-cloud-controller:cloud-compute'
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "2"
        public-address: voldemort.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/5:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: voldemort.maas
          neutron-openvswitch/1:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-1
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: voldemort.maas
          ntp/2:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/ntp-6
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: voldemort.maas
      nova-compute/2:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: "3"
        public-address: weasley.maas
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/6:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: weasley.maas
          neutron-openvswitch/2:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-1
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: weasley.maas
          ntp/3:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/ntp-6
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: weasley.maas
  ntp:
    charm: cs:trusty/ntp-6
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/ntp-8
    exposed: false
    relations:
      juju-info:
      - neutron-gateway
      - nova-compute
      master:
      - ntpmaster
    subordinate-to:
    - neutron-gateway
    - nova-compute
  ntpmaster:
    charm: cs:trusty/ntpmaster-2
    exposed: false
    relations:
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
      master:
      - ntp
      peer:
      - ntpmaster
    units:
      ntpmaster/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 0/lxc/1
        open-ports:
        - 123/udp
        public-address: 10.10.1.151
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/2:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.151
  openstack-dashboard:
    charm: cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-8
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-14
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - openstack-dashboard
      identity-service:
      - keystone
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
    units:
      openstack-dashboard/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 1/lxc/1
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: 10.10.1.159
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/14:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.159
  rabbitmq-server:
    charm: cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-24
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-32
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - cinder
      - glance
      - neutron-api
      - neutron-gateway
      - neutron-openvswitch
      - nova-cloud-controller
      - nova-compute
      cluster:
      - rabbitmq-server
      juju-info:
      - landscape-client
    units:
      rabbitmq-server/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.22.1
        machine: 3/lxc/1
        open-ports:
        - 5672/tcp
        public-address: 10.10.1.161
        subordinates:
          landscape-client/12:
            upgrading-from: cs:trusty/landscape-client-11
            agent-state: started
            agent-version: 1.22.1
            public-address: 10.10.1.161
networks:
  maas-eth1:
    provider-id: maas-eth1
    cidr: 10.10.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this issue when the compute nodes can't resolve their own hostname when sudo commands are executed, resulting in stderr output which breaks most of the command parsing across nova and neutron.

You can check this by running:

```
sudo su -
```

on any compute node - if you get an 'unable to resolve' type message, this is the problem.

This normally points to some sort of misconfiguration in the DNS setup in MAAS

Comment: Yes I know this isssue. I sometimes have issues with my MaaS and having the names show up because of reverse ARP. I will try this early next week with 14.04 instead of 15.04 version of MaaS and report back